# Keyboard layout changes on alt tab

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My Lenovo G40 has a BR layout keyboard that works fine until I bough a US layout mechanical keyboard, after that I cannot set the us layout as default in any way. It aways change to BR, after and after. A simple alt+tab is enough to reconfigure my keyboard settings.

I already tried to run:

- setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant intl -option caps:ctrl_modifier
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

Every command works fine until I change the current windows, that imediatly changes to br layout again.

I want my configurations in that way:

```
squiter@stark:~$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     us
variant:    intl
options:    caps:ctrl_modifier
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(intl)+inet(evdev)+capslock(ctrl_modifier)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(intl)+inet(evdev)+capslock(ctrl_modifier)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
}
```

But every time I change current app window it transform in that:

```
squiter@stark:~$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     br,us
variant:    ,intl
options:    caps:ctrl_modifier
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+br+us(intl):2+inet(evdev)+capslock(ctrl_modifier)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+br+us(intl):2+inet(evdev)+capslock(ctrl_modifier)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

I took some scrrenshots of my configurations: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/14df99r65213vot/AAB5IhOqxOY7d8_RPoTQo8fga?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at another answer (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9277/7446 ) to a related question (about why shift-alt-tab behaviour was strange), and I think it might explain your problem too. In Elementary, go to settings -> keyboard -> layout, and you might find that shift-alt-tab is mapped to switch keyboard layouts. I disabled that mapping, and now alt-tab and shift-alt-tab work fine for me; I'm guessing this will also stop your keyboard layout from changing!